# Can I do with REST any other Operations than CRUD, e.g. BI-functions?

Tags: rest, crud, business-intelligence

I'm searching for a topic for my bachelor thesis. I talked to a research assistant and he told me that there might be a lot of other operations (e.g. BI-functions like trigger actions or calculate something) except of CRUD that you use REST for. He offered me two topic. One of them is to expand a benchmarking framework to be able to handle these operations.

I did some pre-research but couldn't find anything in this direction.
Since the topic sounds really cool I wouldn't like to reject it that fast.

I need a hint what kind of abstract operations there might be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the rest operations are based on HTTP Protocol which support several methods (OPTIONS,HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE also TRACE and CONNECT but not used in REST API)
see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616 for more details

Comment: This answer would be improved by referencing RFC 7231 (which obsoletes 2616), or the HTTP Semantics draft specification (intended to eventually replace RFC 7230 etc)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do with REST any other Operations than CRUD, e.g. BI-functions?

Especially in the context of thesis work, you are going to want to start from [chapter 5 of Fielding's disseration](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

If you read carefully, you'll discover that REST is an architectural style, and the "killer app" built using that architectural style (mostly) is the World Wide Web.

So the question "Can I do BI-functions with REST?" is closely analogous to "Can I create a web interface that implements the application protocol for BI-functions?"

Given that the arrival of the Web was a catastrophic event for legacy information systems generally, I'm going to guess that the answer is "yes, of course".  But what form that might take, and what sorts of standards might emerge from the work is not obvious to me.